# Udhcpd read /etc/hosts like dns

Tags: nginx, dns, hosts, hotspot

I'm building a hotspot with udhcpd and nginx (Linux raspbian, 4.9.41-v7+, armv71). It's working very well, but i want that user enter "home" instead "192.168.2.1" on browser to access my portal.

I set-up the following configurations:
/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       rpi
192.168.2.1     home
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
```

and /etc/udhcpd.conf

```
start 192.168.2.10
end 192.168.2.254
interface wlan0
opt dns 192.168.2.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
opt subnet 255.255.255.0
opt router 192.168.2.1
opt hostname rpi
```

but, when i try access "home/" or "rpi/" the following error appears:

```
Isn't possible to find "home" on DNS server.
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Client config after dhcp ack:

```
Connected to WiFi SSID: rpi
IP: 192.168.2.76
```

Any suggestions?
grateful for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

udhcpd hasn't a build-in dns server. I just switch to dnsmasq and it worked!